# Python : Can't check file's content

Tags: python

I want to check if a string is in a file or not, but i can't seem to get it to work.

```
file = open("test.txt","r+")

username = 'user'
password = 'password'

if username+password in file:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

and the file contains:

```
userpassword
```

it should output 'true' as 'username+password' should be equal to 'userpassword', but the output is 'false',what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file = open("test.txt","r+").read()
```

will return the file contents to `file`. Just doing `file = open("test.txt","r+")` will return a file-like object, you actually have to read the content of the file from the object.

Answer (score 0):

You've opened the file, but haven't read any of the content. Try using `content = file.readlines()` (also, try to avoid using `file` as a variable name - it's also a builtin function)

```
_file = open("test.txt","r+")

username = 'user'
password = 'password'

for line in _file.readlines():
    if username+password in file:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```